# req.params returns undefined for GET route

Tags: node.js

Originally, I was reading query params like `var myId = req.param.("myId");` which was throwing warning messages in the console log regarding deprecated methods.

As suggested by the warning and other similar errors seen by others, I update my code to use a slightly different variant of grabbing query params.

However, when printing the params in the console, I get an `undefined` value for all params.

Not sure why and would appreciate some support. Thanks.

```
   r.get('/sport*', function depart(req, res) {
      var myId = req.params.myId;
      var sportType = req.params.sportType;
      console.log("print params myID", myId);
      console.log("print params sportTYPE", sportType);
   });
}
```

Comment: Params are defined using colon syntax: `/:sportType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for a route like `/sport?myId=123&sportType=football&sportYear=2008` you are actually looking for query strings, here is how you would do :

```
r.get('/sport', function(req, res) {
    var sportType = req.query.sportType;
    var myId = req.query.myId;
    var sportYear = req.query.sportYear;
    console.log("print qS sportTYPE", sportType);
    console.log("print qS sportYear", sportYear);
    console.log("print qS myId", myId);
});
```

If you wanted to use params, you could represent your uri this way (which I find prettier, and is also better for search engines): `/sport/football/2008?myId=123`

And you would declare your route this way :

```
r.get('/sport/:sportType/:sportYear', function(req, res) {
    var myId = req.query.myId;
    var sportType = req.params.sportType;
    var sportYear = req.params.sportYear;
    console.log("print qS sportTYPE", sportType);
    console.log("print qS sportYear", sportYear);
    console.log("print qS myId", myId);
});
```

Comment: Using express and an example route would be something like:

http://mysportserver.local/sport?myId=123&sportType=football&sportYear=2008

Comment: These are query strings, not params, I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was after.

Comment: You're welcome, you can mark the answer as correct :)